# ERROR 000539 when trying to calculate a field and using code block

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539, code-review

**I was given these instructions for an assignment:**

[image]

**However when I am trying to calculate the field I keep getting this error:**

[image]

**I am trying to calculate the field to get something like this:**

[image]

Comment: When you ask coding question add the code as text instead of screenshots of it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

`myCalc` is not the same as `mycalc` that is why it cant find the function.

Make sure to use the [same case](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/is-python-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive) when you define and call the function.